# Making a bot handle logs

Tags: python, discord.py

I would like my bot to be able to handle logs. A log message would be like this:

```
Username: [User]
Stocked items: [Value]
Location: [Value]
Proof: [Image]
```

My goal is to make that when someone reacts to this message, in a certain channel, it will take the user `[user]` as a variable and then do an action with it. The current code I have for it is this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.wait_for()
```

I do not know how to make the bot waits for the reaction, neither how to copy the `[user]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified snippet from the Docs that should fit your needs.

Documentation on `wait_for` can be found [Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for).

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.wait_for()

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ''
    
    try:
        reaction, user = await Me.client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await message.channel.send('')
    else:
        await message.channel.send('')
        with open("users.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(f"""
                    ===========================
                    Username: {message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}
                    ID: {message.author.id}
                    Stocked items: [Value]
                    Location: [Value]
                    Proof: [Image]
                    """)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, maybe drop your second topic around this question, since @hostinfodev has already gave you a piece of answer.

To melt both now, you can see a bot call as a list of arguments separated by spaces. If you know for sure what you'll handle with the command line, you can directly pass the arguments like this :

```
@bot.command(name='log')
async def FuncLog(ctx, stockedItems, location) :
```

Then you have to replace the entries @hostinfodev gave you with the name of variables between {}.

```
f.write(f"""
  ===========================
  Username: {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}
  ID: {message.author.id}
  Stocked items: {stockedItems}
  Location: {location}
  Proof: [Image]
  """)
```

Depending how you declare the image. And even, do you want to save pictures (can take place) or their url ? I haven't touched the items as images yet, but I think it has to be with the "ctx" (in my code) with something like ctx.attachments[0].url

Comment: My message log is actually this one:

'Username: [User]
Stocked Items: [Infos] 
Location: [Info] 
Proof:[Image]'

The last thing I'm looking for is to make [user] a variable as the user could be different from the dsicrod username the person has.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get what you mean. To what would look your command ? 
`!add 15 stash http://.../` -> so each member of your guild (discord server = guild) can add stuff with a proof they have it, or is it a special grade, that then needs to enter the name of the donator ? like : `!add @pluck 15 stash1 url` ? Then you could just save the id of the member, from the ctx (context) or from the argument (@pluck in my example). To contact member by id, use : `.send("<@"+member.id+">")`